# Add store view column to Attribute Grid in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, grid

to list the attribute of a specific store view, I added below code to .../Attribute/Grid.php to _prepareColumns function, but did not work.

```
if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'        => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Store View'),
                'index'         => 'store_id',
                'type'          => 'store',
                'store_all'     => true,
                'store_view'    => true,
                'sortable'      => false,
                'filter_condition_callback'
                                => array($this, '_filterStoreCondition'),
            ));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the code below to Grid.php. It's working to me.

```
      $this->addColumn('store_id', array( 
            'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Registered From (Store)'), 
            'index' => 'store_id', 
            'type' => 'store', 
            'width' => '150px', 
            'store_view'=> true, 
            'display_deleted' => true, 
        ));
```

Hope it helps!